# Tor relay bandwidth not corresponding

Tags: configuration, relays, bandwidth

i've recently started a new relay for support purpose, but in the torrc file i've added this lines:
`BandwidthRate 60 MBytes
 BandwidthBurst 60 MBytes`

But on ATLAS it seems to remain on 250 KB, why my bandwidth arent corresponding?

Comment: You might be interested in the blog post [The lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlas shows an average of *actual* bandwidth, i.e. what was actually used. It does not show the limits, because they are not published anywhere on Atlas: they're set just for reference of your very particular instance of Tor

Comment: The limits are published, Alexey: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n418

Comment: I meant they're not published anywhere on Atlas, updating my answer - thanks for clarification!